# If $lim\: u_n=0$ then show that $\forall \: \epsilon \:\exists N\: n\geq N \Rightarrow (n-N)u_n \leq \epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, alternative-proof

> Suppose $u_n$ is positive and strictly decreasing. Then show that if
>   $\lim u_n=0$ that $$\forall \: \epsilon \:\exists N\: n\geq
>  N \Rightarrow   (n-N)u_n \leq \epsilon$$

This is my attempt.
Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\epsilon \geq 0$ and let's define a sequence $v_n$ such that $v_n=\frac{\epsilon}{n-N}$. The limit of this sequence is zero as $n$ tends to infinity.

Thus $\lim u_n v_n = 0$, and so we have $(n-N)u_nv_n=\epsilon u_n$, as $\epsilon$ is fixed, its limit is still 0. Thus we can conclude that the limit of $(n-N)u_nv_n$ is $0$. Thus the limit of $(n-N)u_n$ is zero. And so $\forall \epsilon \: \exists N \: \forall n\geq N \: lim\:(n-N)u_n=0$.

I just have a bad feeling about my attempt. I don't think I can state that if a limit of a product is $0$ then the limits of both terms is $0$. Any criticism would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that this result holds. You can use $u_n=\frac1n$ to check the result is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\epsilon \geq 0$ and let's define a
>   sequence $v_n$ such that $v_n=\frac{\epsilon}{n-N}$. The limit of this
>   sequence is zero as $n$ tends to infinity.

This limit is indeed zero, alas you did not proof it by an epsilon-delta style proof.

> Thus $\lim u_n v_n = 0$,

Yes, as the individual limits are supposed to exist and both are zero, the limit of the product exists and is zero:
$$
0 = 0 \cdot 0 = \lim u_n \lim v_n = \lim u_n v_n
$$

> and so we have $(n-N)u_nv_n=\epsilon u_n$, as $\epsilon$ is fixed, its
>   limit is still 0.

Indeed if $u_n$ has limit zero and $\epsilon$ is a fixed number then $\epsilon u_n$ has limit zero as well:
$$
\lim \epsilon u_n = \epsilon \lim u_n = \epsilon \cdot 0 = 0
$$

> Thus we can conclude that the limit of $(n-N)u_n v_n$ is $0$.

Yes, by noting the equality 
$$
(n-N) v_n u_n = (n-N) \frac{\epsilon}{n-N} u_n = \epsilon u_n
$$

> Thus the limit of $(n-N)u_n$ is zero.

Your argument seems to be
$$
0 = \lim \, ((n-N) u_n) v_n \Rightarrow \lim (n-N) u_n = 0 \quad (*)
$$

Suppose $u_n$ was defined as
$$
u_n = \frac{1}{n-N}
$$
then this $u_n$ is positive and is strictly decreasing and has $\lim u_n = 0$, thus this $u_n$ is meeting the constraints of the problem and we would have
$$
\lim ((n-N) u_n)v_n 
= \lim \left((n-N) \frac{1}{n-N} \frac{\epsilon}{n-N} \right)
= \lim \frac{\epsilon}{n-N} = 0
$$
but
$$
\lim (n-N) u_n = \lim (n-N) \frac{1}{n-N} = \lim 1 = 1 \ne 0
$$
so your argument $(*)$ is not valid for this $u_n$.

Comment: You're mixing up your $N$'s here, at the end. You've defined $u_n$ in terms of $N$, but then used the same symbol $N$ to refer to the $N_{\epsilon, u}$ whose existence is "guaranteed" by the "theorem" but depends on $(u_n)$ and $\epsilon$.

Comment: I intended just to use that fixed $N$. Where exactly does a $N_{\epsilon, u}$ slip in? Note that I defined that particular sequence $u_n$. That $u_n$ has $\lim u_n = 0$. But I do not use the property that $\lim u_n = 0$.

Comment: "Suppose $u_n$ is defined as $u_n = \frac{1}{n-N}$". This means you now can't use the symbol $N$ in the context of "$\forall \epsilon \exists N$". I just went through your post mentally replacing $N$ with $N_{u, \epsilon}$ where appropriate, to demonstrate where $N$ depends on $u$ and $\epsilon$. When I got to $u_n = \frac{1}{n-N}$, I ended up defining $u_n$ in terms of the sequence $(u)$ and $\epsilon$. If you actually intend $N$ in that line to be completely standalone, then could you please use $M$ instead? ($N$ already has a meaning in the context of this question.)

Comment: I am just giving a counter example to the implication $(*)$. I am not doing any $\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ incantation at that point. "When I got to $u_n=\frac{1}{n−N}$, I ended up defining un in terms of the sequence $(u)$ and $\epsilon$.". Do not do that. Just look at one particular $u_n$, the one defined as $u_n = 1/(n-N)$.

Answer (score 1):

You're right to have the bad feeling, in that $(n-N)u_n v_n \to 0$ does not in general imply $(n-N) u_n \to 0$. (Let $v_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$, and $u_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.) Whether that actually holds in this specific circumstance, with $v_n = \frac{\epsilon}{n-N}$, is what you're trying to prove.

Your aim is to show that if $(u_n)$ is positive and strictly decreasing, then $(x_n) \to 0$ where $x_n = (n-N) u_n$. Does that look plausible to you?

Hint: some of the most useful sanity checks in undergrad analysis are the function $x \mapsto e^x$ and the sequences $(n)$, $(\frac{1}{n})$, $(\frac{1}{n^2})$, and $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$.